# Using OpenGL in Universal Windows App with Angle : glLoadIdentity and glOrtho undefined

Tags: c++, win-universal-app, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently trying to adapt existing OpenGL code to a Universal Windows App, using the Angle component that is supposed to translate OpenGL calls to DirectX.
One base function that is giving me problem is a full screen display of a quad in a texture (in order to apply shaders to that quad).
The regular OpenGL code is straightforward :

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-viewWidth, viewWidth, -viewHeight, viewHeight, -1.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
my_quad.RenderObject();
```

(RenderObject binds the appropriate buffers for vertices and texture coordinates, and then calls glDrawElements).

That code builds and runs fine in regular Win32 applications, using OpenGL and Glut. When trying to use the same code in Angle+UWP, the compiler returns build errors on basic functions :

```
error C2065: 'GL_PROJECTION': undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'glMatrixMode': identifier not found
error C3861: 'glLoadIdentity': identifier not found
error C3861: 'glOrtho': identifier not found
error C2065: 'GL_MODELVIEW': undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'glMatrixMode': identifier not found
error C3861: 'glLoadIdentity': identifier not found
error C2065: 'GL_TEXTURE_ENV': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'GL_MODULATE': undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'glTexEnvf': identifier not found
```

I'm not too familiar with OpenGL ES (obviously), but according to tutorials functions like glLoadIdentity should be supported.
Did I miss anything ? The headers in the Angle folder (gl2.h, glext.h and gl2platform.h) don't define them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angle support only OpenGL-ES 2.0 and 3.0 (3.1 work in progress). Since OpenGL-ES 2.0 removed the whole fixed function pipeline, non of the functions you are using is available with OpenGL-ES 2.0 or higher. Have a look at the [OpenGL-ES 2.0 Reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/).

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that I must use shaders to display my quad ? I actually tried it in my original Win32 program, but since I was displaying the quad to have the texture processed by another shader, I think I was getting conflicts (it wasn't working as expected anyway).

Comment: Yes, you have to use shader and everything.